# Where do I place a docker config.json file when docker is installed as a snap on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, snapcraft

I want to use a custom docker config.json file like this to [reassign the detach keystrokes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files):

```
{
     "detachKeys": "ctrl-q,ctrl-q"
}
```

In a "normal" docker world, i.e. one where docker is installed via apt or similar and not snap, I could put this file in $HOME/.docker/config.json and the setting is picked up when I next run the docker command.  However, this file is not recognized when running /snap/bin/docker.  docker just silently ignores it.

If I try to force it to use this directory, I am denied:

```
$ docker --config .docker/ run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
WARNING: Error loading config file: .docker/config.json: open .docker/config.json: permission denied
```

If I try to locate the file alongside daemon.json in /var/snap/docker/current/config/ this also silently fails to notice any config.json:

```
$ ls -l /var/snap/docker/current/config/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36 Feb 28 11:28 config.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200 Feb 28 09:44 daemon.json

$ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Now, I can force the directory location, but surely there is a better way?

```
$ docker --config /var/snap/docker/current/config/ run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after writing this question, I ran across the answer.  Snap wants this file to go here:

```
$ ls -l ~/snap/docker/current/.docker/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 gclaybur gclaybur 36 Feb 28 12:04 config.json
```

Comment: sometimes the config file might not be in current folder ../snap/docker/current/.docker/ for example it can be  in for example snap/docker/2904/.docker/config.json